# Using same implementaion but got different types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I assume a1 and a2 should have the same type, but why a1 is `false`, while a2 is `boolean`? Another question is why a2 is `boolean`?

```js
type Includes<T extends readonly any[], U> = U extends T[number] ? true : false;
type a1 = boolean extends [true, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7] ? true : false;
type a2 = Includes<[true, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7], boolean>
```

Answer (score 0):

because you check `T[number]`

[number] is position in array

if you check only the T type you get the same result

```js
type Includes<T extends readonly any[], U> = U extends T? true : false;
type a1 = boolean extends [true, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7] ? true : false;
type a2 = Includes<[true, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7], boolean>
```

see example to understend

```js
type IsExtends<T extends any[] >=T[0] extends number ? true : false;
type b1 = IsExtends<[ true ,2,3]> // b1 = false
type b2 = IsExtends<[ 1 ,2,3]> // b2 = true
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgYwDYFcAmEDOAeAKlCAD2AjjUygCcIBDNAeziRChrhAG0BdAGigFUAfFAC8AgsVLkouAPxRglFNABcUAGY0kmCAG4AUKEisAjKKgAjevSS04EkmQodFyvgCY+AZj4BWPgBsfADsXFDyrqoaWjoGRtA07ubwyOhY2C5KEB7efoEhvJbWtmyCQA)

Comment: Can you elaborate why `T[number]` causes the result?